# which of the following integral are uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

which of the  following integral are  uniform  convergence ?

$a)$ $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ sinax}{x}dx , a \in[ a_0, \infty) ,a_0 > 0$

$b)$ $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ sinax}{x}dx , a\in [0, \infty)$

My attempt :  i thinks  both option $a)$ and option $b)$ are  not  uniform convergence$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sinax}{x}dx \le \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx   $

by $p$ test $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p} dx$  is  converge  if $p > 1$

so  both  are  not uniform  convergence

Am i  right ??

Comment: I guess when a is zero, the integral is 0, and it is very different from when a is not 0. And by comparing the function with 1/x, you can say the latter's integral is not convergent, but you perhaps can't say the function sin ax/x 's integral is not comvergent.